# Image placement

Tags: html, css

I've spent couple hours trying to make this work, but it didn't pay off.

I want to make little shop for my Minecraft server.

Big images: image of that buyer is going to buy.

Small images: hyperlinked images that redirect to PayPal paying thing.

I want it to look like this:

[image: image1]

I don't want whole code, just small part or explanation. I'm not HTML/CSS expert.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried but i get image next to big image..Im really new to this, so please forgive me.. http://hastebin.com/begejapoji.xml

Comment: You might want to make a [mcve] but the code still needs to be in the question.

Comment: I made example, this is my code: http://hastebin.com/lekubaseto.xml

Comment: Code **in the question**...with your CSS showing what you have tried.

Comment: I used CSS from Johannes, i dont have any css for shop other than his

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can start with something like this:

```
div { /* <- use a class here! */
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

But you'll need a lot more...
(First of all: Instead of just "div" you'll need to use a class, which you also apply to the DIVs in your HTML code)

see a simple example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBRraB

Comment: But, what should i put in div..?

Comment: It works, THANK YOU, but how can i add 5 spacing between button and big image?

Comment: add `margin-top:5px;` to your css.

Comment: Margin-top:5px; doesn't work, but i just added empty div

Comment: add `img:first-child { margin-bottom: 5px; } (see also updated codepen)